# $transitions.onStart doesn't trigger inside of Angular .run block

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'd like to be able to capture the previous state, however, I can't seem to figure out why the `$transitions.onStart` function doesn't fire properly:

```
  // angular run block

  $transitions.onStart({ from: '*', to: '*' }, (trans) => {
    $rootScope.$previousState = trans.$from().name;
    console.log('HERE?', $rootScope.$previousState)
  });
```

The `console.log` does not trigger ever and whenever I reference the `$rootScope` inside of my `controllers`, I don't see the `$previousState` property that I'm defining inside of this `.run` block.

```
   // sample directive

   restrict: 'A',
    link: (scope, elem) => {
      elem.bind('click', () => {
        console.log('>>>>', $rootScope.$previousState)
        $window.history.back();
      });
    }
```

**UPDATE (FIX) but unsure why:**

So, I updated the code from `$transitions.onStart({ from: '*', to, '*' })` to the following:

```
  $transitions.onStart({}, (trans) => {
    $rootScope.$previousState = trans.$from().name;
  });
```

and this works. What's strange is that the previous syntax used to work and,t hen, suddenly stopped working so I made this change and it now works. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution! The `$transitions.onStart({ from: '*', to, '*' })` syntax implies that it's only watching sate changes at one level, so if you'd like to go further, you'd use the `**` glob pattern.

Furthermore, the `$transitions.onStart(cb)` syntax watches for all state changes.